# How to clickable for selection when using AutoComplete JQuery (ASP.NET, C#)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm doing a task involving the **AutoComplete on textbox** using **JQuery AutoComplete**.

One of the file that I used: [jquery-ui.js](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js)

Then, I need to apply **bold** on the matched text.
For example, if I insert "Jav" in the textbox, they should show up **Jav**a.

and I applied this part and it is successful,

```
open: function (e, ui) {
    var acData = $(this).data('ui-autocomplete');
    acData
    .menu
    .element
    .find('li')
    .each(function () {
        var me = $(this);
        var keywords = acData.term.split(' ').join('|');
        me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), 
        '<b>$1</b>'));
    });  
}
```

However, when I run the textbox, it turns out like this, which I can't select the item and when I hover it, it didn't show up the background color.

[Result before apply the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lCBG.png) |
[Result after apply the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S63o1.png)

Somebody help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

btw, based on what I found from internet, 
just need to replace 
this,

```
me.html(me.text().replace(new RegExp("(" + keywords + ")", "gi"), 
        '<b>$1</b>'));
```

to this,

```
me.html( me.text().replace(regex, function (matched) {
                            return termTemplate.replace('%s', matched);
                        }) );
```

and before the code:

```
$("#<%=test.ClientID %>").autocomplete({
```

I need to put this,

```
var termTemplate = "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>%s</span>";
```

and create the css for `.ui-autocomplete-term` which i put in the `text-weight: bold`

I found out, while sighing how to solve this. and it is okay now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you are replacing the default html markup (needed for the OOB styling to work) with a text value by calling:

```
me.html(me.text(.....));
```

Try retrieving your html and wrap the keyword instead, using something along the lines of:

```
me.html().find(keywords).wrap( "<strong></strong>" )));
```

Comment: sorry, still cannot use it.

Comment: share a fiddle with your code and i'll be glad to help

Comment: it's okay, i already found it. thanks for the response @jcruz